# Running kubernetes on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I'm following [instructions](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.md) for installation of kubernetes on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (running inside Parallels virtual machine). Everything goes well until I run kube-up.sh:

```
# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
... calling kube-up
Deploying master and minion on machine 10.10.103.250

ssh: connect to host 10.10.103.250 port 22: Connection refused
```

Where should I look to find out why is ssh connection refused (verbose mode does not give much info)?

Answer (score 0):

kube-up.sh is failing [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/cluster/ubuntu/util.sh#L414). It uses your default ssh credentials, so verify that you can ssh in from a terminal.

Comment: I know where it's failing but I don't think there is anything on the other side. It is not like the connection is established but authentication fails - while ssh is hanging, `docker ps` shows no docker containers at all.

Comment: Exactly the same issue here running kubernetes inside a Docker container using Ubuntu 14. I'd like to request some guidance how to isolate this error in the kube-up.sh startup procedure, how to check the logs, and how to fix the connectivity to reach the IP address 10.10.103.250.

Comment: It's quite possible the guide at http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/ is out of date. Suggest opening an issue on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new) and cc'ing the guide's maintainer (@resouer).

Answer (score 0):

cluster/ubuntu - Removed due to deprecation and lack of maintenance. 
Please see - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/44344

So cloning master branch (`git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes`) no longer works. You should use old releases to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

If you want to work on Ubuntu 16.04, you can install kubernetes using `kubeadm`