# Kubernetes on Ubuntu over Docker / kube-up does not connect to ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, kubernetes

I'm installing a Kubernetes cluster on a virtual Ubuntu environment, already installed over Docker and Boot2Docker (Windows7/Intel64) components.

I've successfully installed the following software components:

. Boot2Docker
. Docker 1.7.1
. Ubuntu on Docker 14.04
. Latest Kubernetes from GitHub 1.3

and followed the install instructions at: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/

**My questions:**

. Why do I get the error message at kube-up.sh cluster startup:
  ssh: connect to host 10.10.103.250 port 22: Connection timed out;

. How can I produce a log file that shows eventual error messages during the kubernetes cluster startup process;

. Why does the command: 
    `kubectl get nodes` 
  not conect ssh to localhost. Is it active?

**Below the details of the installation flow:**

```
root@a7d243d9a7c5:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

# To activate the container:  
docker start a7d243d9a7c5
docker attach a7d243d9a7c5

# To generate ssh certificates
root@a7d243d9a7c5:~# mkdir ~/.shh
root@a7d243d9a7c5:~# chmod 700 ~/.shh
root@a7d243d9a7c5:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa

root@a7d243d9a7c5:/kubernetes# export PATH="/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries:$PATH"
root@a7d243d9a7c5:/kubernetes# echo $PATH
/kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

root@a7d243d9a7c5:/# export KUBE_VERSION=1.1.8
root@a7d243d9a7c5:/# export FLANNEL_VERSION=0.5.5
root@a7d243d9a7c5:/# export ETCD_VERSION=2.2.0
root@a7d243d9a7c5:/# export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu

cd  kubernetes
./cluster/kube-up.sh
Done! All your binaries locate in kubernetes/cluster/ubuntu/binaries directory
Deploying master and node on machine 10.10.103.250

ssh: connect to host 10.10.103.250 port 22: Connection timed out

kubectl get nodes 
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

The present error is very similar to this report: 
[Running kubernetes on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470696/running-kubernetes-on-ubuntu)

**Update: Why to use Boot2docker**
There are a number of reasons for such construction and the scenarios is not only limited to Windows, but also applies to other base operating systems. First, not to loose the warranted OEM installation of the original manufacturer, that beside commercial web workload also handles energy and device management. Second, the purpose of the Docker environment is primarily to create an isolated development space to execute new package builds with specialized prerequisites, eventually also to run a basic run-time test. At the end of the process the images are uploaded into a cloud environment, having stable behaviour. Yet another point to comment is that a minimal Ubuntu under such environment already demonstrated excellent performance.

Comment: Ubuntu in docker on boot2docker?!? this sounds like a lot of overhead and total inception...
Boot2docker is the 'lightweight' linux distro to run docker in a VM, you should probably install Ubuntu in VirtualBox directly if you really need to use a VM, and then install Kubernetes on that. 
Docker in Docker can be a little tricky. so Docker in Docker in Docker...

Comment: Check my comments in the update (see above).  Need some advice regarding the technical aspects of the installation. The install procedure does not throw any errors at the console prompt, nor the documentation give references where to find the log writing. Please advice how to do problem isolation during the "kube-up.sh" procedure.

Comment: first step is troubleshoot your ssh connection. since you run in a VM, is the VM network setup properly ? with boot2docker you usually don't connect to your local IP but to the boot2docker IP, which you should get from `boot2docker ip` command. after that, I don't know. try setting `set -x` in the script to see what it's doing and where you might find it needs changes for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you can ssh 10.10.103.250 from your master
2. make sure your master can ssh 10.10.103.250 without password